# why it returns SQL exception?

Tags: java, sql

I have a "Manager" class and also one frame which is"Report"  .In the frame I have three radio buttons which their texts are "Years before 1970","between 1970 and 2000","years after 2000" and if one of them is selected , in the text field below these radio buttons I will show the number of rows that have this situation which are in my SQL table.also in my SQL table I have created a table that has name, family, fatherName,motherName,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth,Also the first column is ID which is created automatically .the text in dateOfBirth column is like"December 5, 2009" and I need just its year !!! but when i run this code these stack trace will be shown in the console,why?? please help me.

my Manager class(just a part of that):

```
 public static int getPercent(String i)throws SQLException{
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    List<String> list = null;
    if(i.equals("O")){


        ResultSet rst =  stmt.executeQuery("SELECT dateOfBirth from birthtable");
        while(rst.next()){
           String s1 = rst.getString(6) ;
           if(rst.wasNull()){
               s1=null;
           }
           String s2 = s1.substring(s1.length()-4);
           int s3 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
           if(list ==null&& s3<1970){
               list = new ArrayList<String>();
           }
           else{
               list = new ArrayList<String>();
               s2 = null;
           }
           list.add(s2);
        }


    }
    if(i.equals("N")){

        ResultSet rst =  stmt.executeQuery("SELECT dateOfBirth from birthtable");
        while(rst.next()){
           String s1 = rst.getString(6) ;
           if(rst.wasNull()){
               s1=null;
           }
           String s2 = s1.substring(s1.length()-4);
           int s3 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
           if(list ==null&&s3>2000 ){
               list = new ArrayList<String>();
           }
           else{
               list  = new ArrayList<String>(0);
               s2 = null;
           }
           list.add(s2);
        }
    }
    if(i.equals("H")){
        ResultSet rst =  stmt.executeQuery("SELECT dateOfBirth from birthtable");
        while(rst.next()){
           String s1 = rst.getString(6) ;
           if(rst.wasNull()){
               s1=null;
           }
           String s2 = s1.substring(s1.length()-4);
           int s3 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
           if(list ==null&&s3>1970&& s3<2000 ){
               list = new ArrayList<String>();
           }
           else{
               list  = new ArrayList<String>(0);
               s2 = null;
           }
           list.add(s2);
        }
    }
    return list.size();
}
```

my frame(just a part of that):

```
 private void range1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   int i = 0;
    try {
        i = Manager.getPercent("O");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BirthReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   resulText.setText(i+"");
}
```

stacktarce:

```
      Dec 17, 2009 7:57:48 AM AdminGUI.BirthReport range1ActionPerformed
    SEVERE: null

java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 6 > 1. 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:792)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5529)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5448)
        at database.Manager.getPercent(Manager.java:1137)
        at AdminGUI.BirthReport.range1ActionPerformed(BirthReport.java:152)
        at AdminGUI.BirthReport.access$100(BirthReport.java:23)
        at AdminGUI.BirthReport$2.actionPerformed(BirthReport.java:84)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:291)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
        at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1039)
        at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1091)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1089)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1419)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1372)
        at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:801)
        at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:979)
        at AdminGUI.BirthFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(BirthFrame.java:190)
        at AdminGUI.BirthFrame.access$300(BirthFrame.java:21)
        at AdminGUI.BirthFrame$4.actionPerformed(BirthFrame.java:94)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: What is happening at line 1137 of your Manager class?

Comment: I get it,[:-)]but when "years before 1970" is selected, it will return "1"(I have just one row) but the year is 2006!!

Comment: oh,I get my mistake which I set s2 = null;

Comment: @Johanna - you really need to stop asking StackOverflow to help you debug your code and start learning how to debug it yourself.  Honestly, you won't learn by asking others to solve your problems for you.

Comment: And if you absolutely have to pester other people about your bugs at least listen to what they are saying. You were given a lot of hints in answers to previous questions–pretty much all of them were completely ignored.

Comment: Since already 6 months you are doing homework with Stackoverflow's help... Great... Did you "learned" anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the stack trace!  Look at line 1137 where you call getString(6).  Now look at the error message: java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 6 > 1.  now look at your query: "SELECT dateOfBirth from birthtable".

You are asking (in the query) for 1 value (dateOfBirth) and they you are trying to get it as the 6th value returned... so change the 6 to a.......... 1 and it should work.

You really do need to read the messages - they tell you a lot.

Comment: thanks,[:">] .I fix it ,but when "years before 1970" is selected, it will return "1"(I have just one row) but the year is 2006!!

Comment: well your code is pretty bad to be honest... I was going to show you how to make it better but gave up due to the bugs.  Once you get a working version post the changed code here (just edit your answer and add the working code) and I'll show you how to refactor it to make it better.

What I would do is use the debugger or add some System.out.println() statements so watch what is going on in the code and debug it that way.